# How can i achieve panel overlap in css/bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve this:

[image: Picture of what I am trying to achieve]

I want the three panels in the gray `<div>` to overlap with the white jumbotron above them.  How can I do this in CSS or with Bootstrap?

HTML:

```html
<div id="home-page">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Passionate About Technology?</h3>
    <p>We make and effort to learn something everyday</p>
    <a href="/rush" class="btn btn-danger text-center" id="learn-btn">LEARN</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#home-page        { background: #EFEFEF; }
#home-page .panel { box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray; margin: 15px; }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate the pic you had with a few adjustments to your code:

here is the css:

```
 #home-page {
   background: #EFEFEF; 
 }

  #home-page .panel {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
     margin: 15px;
     margin-top:-50px; 
     height:200px;
  }

 #jumbo{
    height:100px;
 }
```

I also added a div on top to get that effect

```
<div id="jumbo"></div>
```

please see my codepen
http://codepen.io/sammyb123/pen/dMJaRw

Comment: The key here is to set the panel's height and to set the margin-top to negative whatever overlap you want to get the effect.

Answer (score 0):

View below snippet in *Full page*. If you want the same effect on smaller devices then use `col-xs` instead.

```css
#home-page .panel {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
  height: 250px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
#home-page .jumbo-ctr {
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#home-page .panel-ctr {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div id="home-page">
  <div class="container jumbo-ctr">
    <h3>Passionate About Technology?</h3>
    <p>We make and effort to learn something everyday</p>
    <a href="/rush" class="btn btn-danger text-center" id="learn-btn">LEARN</a>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid text-center panel-ctr">
    <div class="row">

      <div class=" col-sm-offset-3  col-sm-2 ">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 ">
        <div class="panel">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 ">
        <div class="panel"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```